# Unable to find errors in XML file

Tags: android, android-layout

I am unable to find errors in an XML file which is showing errors at every `style` name tag.

```
<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@drawable/nav_bar</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/nav_bar</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@drawable/nav_bar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.TabView" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_customize</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.TabBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <item name="background">@color/space_menu</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/space_menu</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@color/space_menu</item>
</style>

<style name="Sherlock.__Widget.Holo.Spinner" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/abs__list_selector_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/box_element</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left|center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerMode">dropdown</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:width">200dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Is this your complete xml?

Comment: You have to provide more than just this file. What is the error you are getting?Is this your complete xml? etc...

Comment: possible duplicate of [error in android xml style file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299255/error-in-android-xml-style-file)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your complete xml, you are missing the root node

```
<resources>
...
</resources>
```

From the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html)

> Required. This must be the root node.

If you have this please post complete xml and tell us what the error messsage is and I will delete or edit.

Comment: no i have mentioned the resources tag still its displaying the error

Comment: Then post the full xml and/or what the error message is. Have you tried cleaning?