# error in android xml style file

Tags: android, android-layout

this is the complete xml file
and error occurs at starting of each style name tag in this xml file

```
<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@drawable/nav_bar</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/nav_bar</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@drawable/nav_bar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.TabView" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_customize</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.TabBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <item name="background">@color/space_menu</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/space_menu</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@color/space_menu</item>
</style>

<style name="Sherlock.__Widget.Holo.Spinner" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/abs__list_selector_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/box_element</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left|center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerMode">dropdown</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:width">200dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your `<style>` tags in `<resources>` tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@drawable/nav_bar</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/nav_bar</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@drawable/nav_bar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.TabView" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_customize</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.TabBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <item name="background">@color/space_menu</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/space_menu</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@color/space_menu</item>
</style>

<style name="Sherlock.__Widget.Holo.Spinner" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/abs__list_selector_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/box_element</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left|center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerMode">dropdown</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:width">200dp</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: i have wrapped it in resources tag still the error crops up

Comment: Is it in res/values folder?

Comment: yes it is in res/values and same kind of errors are occuring for themes.xml loacted in res/values folder as well

Comment: Could you please post text of error message? This file works fine in my test project.

Comment: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 
 'Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.

Comment: Do you have ActionBarSherlock library attached to your project? Check it in Project -> Properties -> Android -> Library section.

Comment: Does my answer help you to resolve your question? Could you mark it as a solution?